# How to load Jinja2 template with values after form submission

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, jinja2

I have a form in a Jinja2 template. This is what I'm trying to do with it:

- After a user submits the form, a handler in the backend enqueues an
  asynchronous task.
- The handler then reloads the current page with the form filled
  with the user provided values.

What is the best way to do this ?
For example say I have a `<select>` input in my form that looks like this:

```
  <select id="shift_selected" name="shift_selected">
  {% for shift in Shifts %}
    <option value="{{ shift }}" {{ 'selected' if shift == selected_shift }}>{{ shift }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
  </select>
```

Now to re render the page after the form has been submitted,

- my handler has to parse the input, get the value of 'shift_selected'
- Then set the value of 'selected_shift'.

args['selected_shift'] = self.request.get("selectedShift")

template.render(args)

The handler essentially receives some data in form    values and    sends the same data back as a template variable value. Is    there a    better way to do this. If done for a long form this method is quite tedious.

Comment: The `post` (collecting the user input) and the `get` (redrawing the page) ops are 2 separate client requests, the web server has no clue that they are in fact related (may process a pile of other requests in between the 2 related ones), so the server-side app needs to parse and persist each piece of data (the entire context) to be shared across the requests and *make* them related.

Comment: If the form filling-logic is entirely self-contained (doesn't require additional server side info) it's also possible to run it on the client side (a JS script for example) and just post the collected data to the server (to a different handler) - but I don't know if/how jinja templates could be used in such scenario (or if this falls into your question's context).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can even pass `request` object as a param to Jinja template. Or write a function to copy all the GET or POST parameters in `request` to Jinja template parameters.

```
args['request'] = self.request
template.render(args)

<select id="shift_selected" name="shift_selected">
{% for shift in request.get('selectedShift') %}
    <option value="{{ shift }}" {{ 'selected' if shift == selected_shift }}>{{ shift }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: Do you have an example of how the request object will be rendered in the template if it is directly passed.